# Search for particular fields and print them in new file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, command

I am searching for one line command to search for few words in 'myfile.txt' and if pattern match then cut that words and print it in new file.

myfile.txt.

```
162.23.55.222 - - [07/Dec/2013:00:40:35 +0000] 0.033 POST /view/SBEventListComponentController?componentUid=comp_00008OM8 HTTP/1.1 200 77282 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11 http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/homepage 6476CC940C83EDF031FF2564EE108993.ecomprodsw012
162.16.87.1973 - - [07/Dec/2013:00:40:34 +0000] 0.131 POST /view/SBEventListComponentController?componentUid=comp_000080KW HTTP/1.1 200 82707 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11 http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/homepage 6476CC940C83EDF031FF2564EE108993.ecomprodsw012
162.23.22.542, 10.32.30.1 - - [07/Dec/2013:00:40:35 +0000] 0.224 GET /view/content/homepage HTTP/1.1 200 66233 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.66 Safari/535.11 - 6476CC940C83EDF031FF2564EE108993.ecomprodsw012
```

My output.txt must contains.

```
162.23.55.222 07/Dec/2013:00:40:35 http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/homepage 6476CC940C83EDF031FF2564EE108993.ecomprodsw012
162.16.87.1973 07/Dec/2013:00:40:34 http://sportsbeta.ladbrokes.com/homepage 
162.23.22.542, 10.32.30.1 07/Dec/2013:00:40:35
```

How can I search for more patterns and redirect it to another file.
I din't get why this down vote. I tried cut, grep and sed commands. But din't get expected results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you indeed want the last field `6476…`, which is present in lines 1 and 2 of "myfile.txt", to appear only in line 1 of "output.txt"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to more or less do what I think you are asking.  The first row of your output example includes the field at the end of the line but the second doesn't - I can't immediately see why

```
perl -l -n -a -e '($u)=/(http:\S+)/; if ($F[0] =~/,$/) { print "@F[0..1] ", substr($F[4],1) } else { print $F[4]," ", substr($F[3],1)," ", $u}' infile.txt infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung . In first field if character is ',' I need to continue and take it as field one only. Like in third line. Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: sorry no idea, your explanation doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: There are two IP address in third line of myfile.txt. With the above code I am missing one IP address and i am getting 162.23.22.542, 07/Dec/2013:00:40:35 . How to get both IP address of third line??

Comment: altered it to take that into account